# Does Signalr negotiate requests cause 503 Service Unavailable Error?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, signalr, http-status-code-503

I'm using asp.net core 5 with signalr.

I saw a negotiate request that was **600 bytes** 50 times per minute for **13 hours** in the IIS log(total: **5070000 request, ~3GB data**).

I got the "**503 Service Unavailable Error**" error 2 times today.

why so?

@Brennan this way down below 2 hub, jwt, refreshtoken, reconnonecting

Clent Code:

```
var baseHubAddr = "https://localhost:5001/";
var loginHub, roomHub;
var nick;

var token;

var intervalRefreshToken, intervalSendRanks;


function init() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    script.onload = () => {
        preInit();
    };
    script.src = baseHubAddr + "lib/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js";
}

function preInit() {
    loginHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(baseHubAddr + "login")
        .configureLogging("debug")
        .withAutomaticReconnect({
            nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: retryContext => {
                reconnectFunc(retryContext);
            }
        })
        .build();

    loginHub.onreconnected(connectionId => {
        refreshToken();
    });

    loginHub.on("RefreshToken", function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (response.success) {
            token = response;
        }
        else {
            console.error("RefreshToken");
        }
    });

    loginHub.on("Login", function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (response.success) {

            intervalRefreshToken = setInterval(refreshToken, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            token = response;

            roomHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(baseHubAddr + "room", {
                    accessTokenFactory: () => {
                        return token.jwtToken;
                    }
                })
                .configureLogging("debug")
                .withAutomaticReconnect({
                    nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: retryContext => {
                        reconnectFunc(retryContext);
                    }
                })
                .build();

            roomHub.onreconnecting(error => {
                console.assert(roomHub.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Reconnecting);
            });

            roomHub.onreconnected(connectionId => {
                console.assert(roomHub.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Connected);

                roomHub.invoke("ReOpenRoom", roomConfig.roomId).catch(function (err) {
                    return console.error(err.toString());
                });
            });

            roomHub.onclose(error => {
                console.assert(roomHub.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected);
            });

            roomHub.start()
                .then(function () {
                
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return console.error( err.toString());
                });
        }
        else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.errors));
        }
    });

    loginHub.start().then(function () {
        nick = prompt("Nick:", "");

        if (nick) {
            let pwd = prompt("Password:", "");

            if (pwd) {
                loginHub.invoke("Login", nick, pwd).catch(function (err) {
                    return console.error(err.toString());
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("Password!");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Nick!");
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error( err.toString());
    });
}

function refreshToken() {
    loginHub.invoke("RefreshToken", token.userId, token.refreshToken).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
}


function reconnectFunc(retryContext) {
    if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 100) {
        return 50;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 1000) {
        return 300;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 10000) {
        return 1000;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 45000) {
        return 5 * 1000;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 2 * 60 * 1000) {
        return 10 * 1000;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 5 * 60 * 1000) {
        return 60 * 1000;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 10 * 60 * 1000) {
        return 3 * 60 * 1000;
    }
    else if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 15 * 60 * 1000) {
        return 5 * 60 * 1000;
    }
    else {
        return 10 * 60 * 1000;
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: Show your client code

Comment: @Brennan i updated my post with client code.